# Распознать число в не-0-терминированной строке

Tags: c++, c, arm

Имеется строка, представленная в виде пары итераторов либо в виде указателя на `char` и длины. Особенность строки такова, что в ней

- может содержаться число, но только одно;
- может содержаться ошибочное значение (лишние символы, либо число с переполнением);
- может не быть ничего (`begin+1 = end`).

Известные мне функции стандартной библиотеки C и C++, а именно `atoi`, `std::stoi`, `sscanf` требуют нуль-терминированную строку. Есть ли подобные стандартные функции в библиотеках C и C++? К этим функциям также предъявляются требования:

- функция не должна динамически выделять память в куче;
- функция не должна использовать VLA;
- функция не должна бросать исключений.

Хотя заявлено, что IAR EWARM 8.40.1 поддерживает C++17, но в нём не оказалось класса `std::string_view` и функции `std::from_chars`. Последняя выглядит как наиболее подходящая, хотя и нигде не написано, выделяет ли она для внутренних нужд память в куче.

Comment: если `std::string_view` не подвезли, то, как вариант, есть задепрекаченый `std::strstream`... правда на счёт аллокации и исключений надо проверить... если boost на столе, то есть `boost::iostreams::array`...

Comment: Список наложенных ограничений выглядит как типовое домашнее задание по программированию, суть которого написать свою собственную реализацию, а не найти библиотечную.

Comment: В вопросе пропущен самый важный момент — что такое "число"? Является ли, например, числом строка "0xFF" или "100 000"?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, список наложенных ограничений исходит из ограниченных ресурсов микроконтроллера. В нём я избегаю лишнего копирования и выделения памяти. Что является числом? Всё это, конечно, является, но сейчас речь идёт о сплошных числах (без пробелов и других разделителей) в десятичной системе счисления.

Comment: "не быть ничего" и `begin+1 = end` - разные вещи. Во втором случае в строке есть один символ.

Comment: `sscanf` можно заставить работать на сроке без терминатора.

Comment: Для МК я бы написал собственный однопроходный парсер на основе конечного автомата

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, согласен, здесь ошибка. Должно быть `begin=end`. `sscanf`, если ему передать длину числа в формате,  наверное не будет доходить до конца строки. Но раз в документации сказано, что нужна нуль-терминированная строка, то надо этому следовать. Детали реализации этой функции же не раскрываются.

Comment: Вы правы, гарантий нет. `sscanf` не годится.

Comment: ещё, кстати, вспомнил: есть же Сишный `strtol()`

Comment: @Fat-Zer, If str does not point to a valid C-string, or if endptr does not point to a valid pointer object, it causes undefined behavior. Там endptr - это не итератор конца, а указатель на указатель, по которому записывается адрес того символа, где, по мнению этой функции, заканчивается очередное число.

Comment: @maestro, да, прошу прощения... что-то меня перемкнуло... показалось, что endptr — это и входной и выходной параметр...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из "сложных" операций понадобится умножение на десять, которое можно заменить на три сдвига и одно сложение:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool parse_uint(int n, const char s[/* n */], unsigned *result) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    unsigned r = 0;
    for (const char *p = s; p < s + n; ++p) {
        if (!isdigit((unsigned char)*p)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (r > UINT_MAX / 10u) {
            return false;
        }
        r *= 10u;
        const unsigned d = *p - '0';
        if (r > UINT_MAX - d) {
            return false;
        }
        r += d;
    }
    *result = r;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned n;
    assert(parse_uint(1, "0", &n));
    assert(n == 0);
    assert(parse_uint(1, "1", &n));
    assert(n == 1);
    assert(parse_uint(2, "10", &n));
    assert(n == 10);
    assert(parse_uint(10, "4294967295", &n));
    assert(n == 4294967295);
    assert(!parse_uint(10, "4294967296", &n));
    assert(!parse_uint(11, "42949672950", &n));
    assert(!parse_uint(3, "1_2", &n));
    assert(!parse_uint(0, "0", &n));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Do I need to cast to unsigned char before calling toupper(), tolower(), et al.?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21805674)

Comment: @wololo, спасибо. Добавил приведение.

Comment: Де-факто поведение `isdigit` не предсказуемо. [Can isdigit legitimately be locale dependent in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2898228)

Comment: Согласен, такая проверка на переполнение более универсальна.

Answer (score 0):

> #### ⚠️ Судя по всему, это решение предполагает, что завершающий 0 всё же есть в области, чтение которой доступно без UB, но не обязательно сразу за концом подстроки.
>
> Подробнее в комментариях к ответу.

`sscanf` всё умеет (прочем, переполнение int'а я проверять не стал): [playground](https://tio.run/##XZFRb4IwFIXf@yuuLExQWAA3YVH8I9semlIcCS2EFuNi/O2sFIXCkz2n51y/S0ld@2dCuu6l4KRsMwpHImRWVCc0OUUlZEMxOyHUioKfgWNGRY0JBZU9IHSpigxyh1RcSCC/uIGN8MCU1EU3BFBwCRxSoL7wQ1VUTg4Oh1MKgasUQN2oTO5Ya/ttI9bglJSDnbngg@UB90DN5a7RPI7FVgrHKvgFlwoGN@eWUS6FpcIAtBRUF1bcTFNWyz8FpdSUUz83ndHkedUwLL920c9Bm@IBOPgeWLZtZ5ltc2sA6zP9llcP2KMhCOa5o8CfnVd1@eqwNHCHTZ67rFJgA95yHQNxhDS/Vo0bQdXWQn2r7x7lqrN3dEeop2G44M7wBLNHUk9h@WG0e//w93HyGehjf7I0mKYWrnHehnrwQ0SmiE2RmCIMxhHbcNYb5G4u47lM5tIcttfGlB/0VIgX9/F4/5yYaJxg@ovBCJdGtDR65nvX/QM)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f(const char *s, const char *e)
{
  int n = e-s-1;

  if (n >= 0)
    printf("'%.*s' (len %d) - ", n, s, n);
  else
    printf("(len %d) - ", n);

  if (n < 0)
    puts("invalid arguments");
  else if (!n)
    puts("empty input");
  else
  {
    char format[32];
    sprintf(format, "%%%dd%%n", n);
    int x, m;
    sscanf(s, format, &x, &(m=0));

    if (n != m)
      puts("invalid input");
    else
      printf("parsed as %d\n", x);
  }
}

int main()
{
  const char *s = "-12345-67890123456789";

  f(s, s);

  f(s, s+1);
  f(s, s+2);
  f(s, s+7);
  f(s, s+8);
  f(s, s+10);

  f(s+1, s+2);
  f(s+1, s+3);
  f(s+1, s+7);
  f(s+1, s+8);
  f(s+1, s+10);

  f(s+6, s+17);
  f(s+6, s+18);
  f(s+7, s+17);
  f(s+7, s+18);

  f(s+18, s+20);
  f(s+18, s+21);
  f(s+18, s+22);
  f(s+18, s+23);
  f(s+18, s+100000);
}
```

```
(len -1) - invalid arguments
'' (len 0) - empty input
'-' (len 1) - invalid input
'-12345' (len 6) - parsed as -12345
'-12345-' (len 7) - invalid input
'-12345-67' (len 9) - invalid input
'' (len 0) - empty input
'1' (len 1) - parsed as 1
'12345' (len 5) - parsed as 12345
'12345-' (len 6) - invalid input
'12345-67' (len 8) - invalid input
'-678901234' (len 10) - parsed as -678901234
'-6789012345' (len 11) - parsed as 1800922247
'678901234' (len 9) - parsed as 678901234
'6789012345' (len 10) - parsed as -1800922247
'7' (len 1) - parsed as 7
'78' (len 2) - parsed as 78
'789' (len 3) - parsed as 789
'789' (len 4) - invalid input
'789' (len 99981) - invalid input
```

Comment: Известны реализации `sscanf` который вызывают `strlen` перед началом работы. :(

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, откуда известны? По стандарту вроде не должен?

Comment: Стандарт не указывает реализацию, но явно говорит "С string" что разрешает `strlen`.

Comment: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=26302744

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923924/why-is-glibcs-sscanf-vastly-slower-than-fscanf-on-linux/23924112#23924112

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, неожиданно. Пофиксили в итоге?

Comment: Нет: https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/strops.c.html#41

Comment: Сама идея красивая.

Comment: а ещё `sprintf()` может аллоцировать память...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, разве? Зачем ему?

Comment: @Qwertiy, честно сказать, я уже не совсем уверен... помню, что в обработчике сигнала старался её избегать и вроде бы из-за аллокации... вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570170/does-sprintf-snprintf-allocate-additional-memory) также пишут, что в glibc и newlibc она может аллоцировать при некоторых обстоятельствах, но при каких ни найти ни воспроизвести у меня сейчас не получилось...

Comment: [Does sscanf("123456789123456789123456789", "%d", &n) have defined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44740449)

Comment: @wololo, а если `%u`?)

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, конкретный спецификатор преобразования роли не играет. Если точный математический результат преобразования не представим целевым типом — поведение не определено.

Comment: @wololo, ну вообще, странно. От scanf'а при адекватном формате никак не должно быть UB, иначе любая программа, содержащая scanf содержит UB просто потому, что пользователи могут ввести больше цифр в int. А программа с UB может рассматриваться как уязвимая. В общем, что-то тут не то...

Comment: Добро пожаловать в C.

Comment: @wololo, не, тут явно что-то не то...

Comment: `программа, содержащая scanf содержит UB просто потому, что пользователи могут ввести больше цифр в int.` UB нет пока ввод не переполняет `int`, но как только произошло переполнение, то UB. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694266), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28007600), [3](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.std.c/c/7mSxlJir4Eo), [4](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.std.c/c/P-VPAMpZu9c).

Comment: @wololo, но у тебя нет возможности проверить ввод и предотвратить UB, а значит оно есть?

Comment: Идея та же, что и здесь: `int x = ..., y = ..., z = x / y;`. Компилятор имеет право предполагать, что `y` никогда не равен нулю. И до тех пор пока он действительно не равен нулю, результат однозначно определён. Пока ввод `scanf` не переполняет `int` (или иной тип в зависимости от передаваемых аргументов), поведение однозначно определено.

Answer (score -1):

Вот моя реализация такой функции.

```
namespace Internal {
    inline uint32_t MultiplyAccumulate(uint32_t m1, uint32_t m2, uint32_t add, bool &overflow)
    {
        uint32_t ovf = 0;
        //В инструкции MUL набора инструкций thumb-2 поведение флага C не определено. Поскольку работаем с 
        //беззнаковыми числами, а слишком больших чисел не ожидается, можно заменить проверку переполнения флагом N.
        //После операции сложения проверяются флаги S и V. 
        asm volatile ("B calc \n"
                        "ovf: mov %6, #1 \n"
                        "B fin \n"
                        "calc: \n"
                        "muls %0, %1, %2 \n"
                        "BMI ovf \n"
                        "adds %3, %4, %5 \n"
                        "BVS ovf \n"
                        "BCS ovf \n"
                        "fin:"
                            :: "r"(m1), "r"(m1), "r"(m2), 
                                "r"(m1), "r"(m1), "r"(add),
                                "r"(ovf));
        overflow = (bool)ovf;
        return m1;
    }
};

/// \brief Преобразование массива символов в число
/// \details Функция принимает массив в виде пары итераторов и
/// выполняет преобразование его в число. 
/// \param begin Итератор начала массива
/// \param end Итератор конца массива
template<typename Iterator>
std::experimental::optional<uint32_t> ParseUint32(const Iterator begin, const Iterator end)
{
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;
    auto rbegin = std::make_reverse_iterator(end);
    auto rend = std::make_reverse_iterator(begin);
    
    uint32_t result = 0;
    int radix = 1;
    bool overflow = 0;
    for (auto it = rbegin; it != rend; it++, radix *= 10)
    {
        if (*it < '0' || *it > '9')
            return std::experimental::nullopt;
        uint32_t val = *it - '0';
        result = Internal::MultiplyAccumulate(val, radix, result, overflow);
        if (overflow)
        {
            return std::experimental::nullopt;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Для остальных типов можно реализовать аналогично.

Comment: Можно обойтись умножением на константу или вообще без умножения.